# C# - Asp.Net : Update panel not updating in SignalR hub.on method

Tags: asp.net, signalr, updatepanel, code-behind, signalr.client

I'm trying to add an item i receive from the server to a list in codebehind inside the SignalR hub.on method. After it gets added to the list, the update panel should update and show up on the front end. The item gets added to the list, but the updatepanel doesn't update. When i do a manual refresh of the page in the browser, then i can see the added item just fine. I also added a button to update the update panel after the hub.on method gets fired, and again it works fine. Just that when trying to update the updatepanel inside the hub.on method, nothing happens. 
Note : The hub.on method is inside the Page_Load method.

This is the hub.on method :

```
SignalRService.ServerHub.On<string, string>("commandMessage", (param, param1) =>
        {
            if (param.Equals("addConnectedClient"))
            {
                string[] sUserDetails = param1.Split(',');
                string sUserName = sUserDetails[2]; //The item i want to add
                DEBUG_AddPendingUser(sUserName);
                updatepanelusers.Update();
            }
        });
```

This is the aspx code of the updatepanel :

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelusers" style="display: none;" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="userspending" runat="server" class="exercisepage pageleft"></div>
                <div id="usersaccepted" runat="server" class="exercisepage pageleft2"></div>
                <div id="usersdenied" runat="server" class="exercisepage pageright2"></div> 
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! As i can't wrap my head around why this is happening.

Comment: Why are you using an UpdatePanel if you have SignalR? Just call some JavaScript on the client side to update the page. Don't bother with garbage abstractions like UpdatePanel.